# How to apply condition on ffill?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I was wondering how can I use ffill on C_01_01_ActionPlan and C_01_03_StatusValue with a condition that if cell value is None on C_01_03_StatusValue and if previous cell = "In Progress" then copy down previous cell text from both the column

Here is a text view

```
Report_Due_Date         C_01_03_StatusValue C_02_01_ActionPlan
1/1/2020                None                None
2/1/2020                Supplier network    In Progress
3/1/2020                Supplier network    In Progress
4/1/2020                Installation        In Progress
5/1/2020                None                None
6/1/2020                Telematics tool.    In Progress
7/1/2020                None                None
8/1/2020                None                None
```

Current

[image: Pic 1]

Expected:

[image: Pic 2]

```
if df[df['C_01_03_StatusValue']] is None and df['C_01_03_StatusValue'].shift()=='In Progress':
      df['C_01_03_StatusValue'] = df['C_01_03_StatusValue'].ffill()
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: And also, add what you have tried, see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You really should provide your examples as text,  not images.  I don't see anything different in your example from standard capability `df.fillna(method="ffill")`

Comment: Thank you all for your comment, @RobRaymond the column C_01_03_StatusValue won't always be "In Progress" that's why I need condition

Comment: @VatsalPatel it would really help if you show what you are trying to achieve with data that's usable without someone like me having to use OCR

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `df.fillna(method='ffill')` as it will help in forward fill of the data and might be useful

Answer (score 0):

The only approach I can see, is rollback a `fillna()` to what it was if you don't want it.   using `loc[mask]` type approach does not work either.

```
import re
data = """Report_Due_Date         C_01_03_StatusValue  C_02_01_ActionPlan
1/1/2020                None                None
2/1/2020                Supplier network    In Progress
3/1/2020                Supplier network    In Progress
4/1/2020                Installation        In Progress
5/1/2020                None                None
6/1/2020                Telematics tool.    In Progress
7/1/2020                None                None
8/1/2020                None                None"""
a = [[t.strip() for t in re.split("  ",l) if t!=""]  for l in data.split("\n")]

df = pd.DataFrame(a[1:],columns=a[0])
df = df.replace({"None":None})
df.assign(
    OldC_01_03_StatusValue=df["C_01_03_StatusValue"],
    OldC_02_01_ActionPlan=df["C_02_01_ActionPlan"],
    C_01_03_StatusValue=df["C_01_03_StatusValue"].fillna(method="ffill"),
    C_02_01_ActionPlan=df["C_02_01_ActionPlan"].fillna(method="ffill"),
).assign(
    C_01_03_StatusValue=lambda dfa: np.where(dfa["OldC_02_01_ActionPlan"].shift()!="In Progress",
                                            dfa["OldC_01_03_StatusValue"],
                                            dfa["C_01_03_StatusValue"]
                                            ),
    C_02_01_ActionPlan=lambda dfa: np.where(dfa["OldC_02_01_ActionPlan"].shift()!="In Progress",
                                            dfa["OldC_02_01_ActionPlan"],
                                            dfa["C_02_01_ActionPlan"]
                                            )
).drop(["OldC_01_03_StatusValue","OldC_02_01_ActionPlan"], axis=1)
```